# How to open a link in a new window with ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, target, new-window, button-to

```
<li class="li_spacing"><%= button_to "Website", @restaurant.website, :target => '_blank', :class => "btn btn-primary" %></li>
```

Everything works except for `:target => '_blank'`. Why does this not render the the link in a new page?

Answer (score 3):

Change from `button_to` to a `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to "Website", @restaurant.website, target: "_blank" %>
```

`button_to` is generated inside a form, if you still wish to use it:

```
button_to "Website", @restaurant.website, class: 'btn btn-primary', form: {target: '_blank'}
```

Answer (score 2):

A common way to open a link in a new window was to add a `target="_blank"` to the link tag.

But **for [security reasons](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/) this should not be done** anymore. It is recommended to use `rel=noreferrer` instead:

```
link_to 'title', url, rel: 'noreferrer'
```

Or as a button:

```
button_to 'title', url, form: { rel: 'noreferrer' }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @spickermann. Will those security reasons apply only to user generated content? In other words, will target="_blank" be ok for links where the content will not be user generated?

Comment: I would argue that the `rel: 'noreferrer'` protect the browser from malicious content no matter if it was user-generated or explicitly written by the website owner itself. The website owner might think that there is no malicious on their site and therefore the `noreferrer` is not needed. But from the user's point of view there is no difference. The user doesn't care if the malicious content was user-generated or explicitly placed by the website owner. Therefore IMHO just always use `malicious ` to indicate that you care about protecting the user.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `button_to` helper then it is automatically wrapped in a form by rails. So what you can do is to pass the attribute `target: '_blank'` as:

```
button_to "Website", @restaurant.website, class: 'btn btn-primary', form: {target: '_blank'}
```